# Swapping Image on Mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have one linked image at the top of the page, and 5 linked images below it. When mouse over the images below, the top image should change to the image moused-over and link of the moused-over, it should also be twice the size but I can't even get it to change image/link.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("google").mouseenter(function() {
        $("big").attr({
        "href": "http://i.imgur.com/oO1RrsF.png?1",
        "src": "http://www.google.com".
    });
});
$("apple").mouseenter(function() {
        $("big").attr({ 
        "href" : "http://www.apple.com",
        "src" : "http://i.imgur.com/eHm7Nbg.png?1"
    });
});

$("facebook").mouseenter(function() {
        $("big").attr({
        "href" : "http://www.facebook.com",
        "src" : "http://i.imgur.com/ovkudjR.png?2"
    });
});

$("hooli").mouseenter(function() {
        $("big").attr({
        "href" : "http://www.hooli.xyz",
        "src" : "http://i.imgur.com/yfEYkoZ.png?2"
    });
});

$("piedpiper").mouseenter(function() {
        $("big").attr({
        "href" : "http://www.piedpiper.com",
        "src" : "http://i.imgur.com/Q3IhTeK.jpg?1"
    });
});
});
```

`big` is the id for the top image. I'm putting the id tag in the `<a href>` wrapped around the img tags. I've been playing around with it for awhile, and nothing is working. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors are wrong. You want either of the following.

```
$("#google"); //ID google
$(".google"); //Class google
```

And likewise for all other selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Use # for selecting ID and . for selecting class in order to access the element .
And then change the source of selected element on mousemove as  you have done .

Answer (score -1):

Demo [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3b5wj7j9/)

**HTML**

```
 <a href="" id="big_a"><img src="" href="" id="big" /></a>
```

**CSS**

```
 #big {
     width:500px;
     height:200px;
 }
 .small {
     border:1px solid black;
 }
```

**Script**

```
 var lists = {
     "google": {
         href: "http://www.google.com",
         src: "http://i.imgur.com/oO1RrsF.png?1"
     },
         "apple": {
         href: "http://i.imgur.com/oO1RrsF.png?1",
         src: "http://i.imgur.com/eHm7Nbg.png?1"
     },
         "facebook": {
         href: "http://www.facebook.com",
         src: "http://i.imgur.com/ovkudjR.png?2"
     },
         "hooli": {
         href: "http://www.hooli.xyz",
         src: "http://i.imgur.com/yfEYkoZ.png?2"
     },
         "piedpiper": {
         href: "http://www.piedpiper.com",
         src: "http://i.imgur.com/Q3IhTeK.jpg?1"
     }

 }

 $.each(lists, function (i, e) {
     $("<a target='_blank' id='anc_" + i + "' href='" + e.href + "'><img class='small' src='" + e.src + "' id='" + i + "' alt='" + i + "'/></a><br>").appendTo("body");
     $("#" + i).mouseenter(function () {
         $("#big").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
         $("#big_a").attr("href", $("#anc_" + $(this).attr("id")).attr("href"));
     });
 });
```